# What is the difference between worldsheet supersymmetry and spacetime supersymmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry

What is the difference between worldsheet supersymmetry and spacetime supersymmetry? For worldline formulation of fermions quantum mechanics, there is a supersymmetry. But the corresponding spacetime theory (namely, QFT) is totally void of supersymmetry. Now to have fermionic excitations for strings, we need to add supersymmetry to the worldsheet, then how does the worldsheet supersymmetry induce spacetime supersymmetry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Worldsheet supersymmetry* is the fermionic symmetry of the worldsheet RNS action under the worldsheet supsresymmetry transformations that look like
$$ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}}X \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}}X + \mathrm{i}\bar{\epsilon}\psi^\mu$$
and which I'm too lazy to type out for all fields (and which also depend on whether or not we're looking at the gauge-fixed or non-gauge-fixed version). $\epsilon(\sigma,\tau)$ here is an unconstrained worldsheet Majorana fermion parametrizing the transformation. It is a symmetry of the *classical action of the superstring*.

On the other hand, *spacetime supersymmetry* is the symmetry of the low-energy effective 10d SUGRA action that describes the massless spectrum of its corresponding string theory. It is one of the "accidents" of string theory that the GSO projection works exactly in such a way that the retained bosonic and fermionic states organize into 10d supersymmetry multiplets, since the 2d supersymmetry of the worldsheet theory does not a priori force this to be the case.

Comment: Once we have gravitinos in the spectra, unitarity dictates that we must have a local susy in the target space, so it is not an accident, it is a consequence from unitarity.

Answer (score 0):

World-sheet supersymmetry is the mathematical fact that the Ramond sector has equal numbers of fermionic and bosonic states at each mass level. Recall that we can test the pairs of states at each level of the tower with the fermion number operator and notice this fact.

Some exotic computations involving “aequatio identica satis abstrusa” give a first taste of the nature of spacetime supersymmetry. Spacetime supersymmetry is obtained by combining  R- and NS+ .

There has been a downvote on this answer in the past, so
let me follow up with two quotes from Zwiebach's text and more context.

Will be quoting from Zwiebach's text: A First Course in String Theory, Second Edition.

The quotes would be words mostly but the calculations (*simple* and *tractable*) are found on the same pages if you want to see where the statements are coming from.

**Quote 1 page 317 of Zwiebach's text**: "We have separated the states in two groups with identical number of states: to the left of
the bars we find the states with $(−1)^F = −1$ (fermionic states) and to the right of the bars the states with $(−1)^F = +1$ (bosonic states). Note that for each state to the left, there is a
corresponding state to the right built on a ground state of opposite fermion number. The appearance of an equal number of bosonic and fermionic states at every mass level is a
signal of supersymmetry. **This is, however, supersymmetry on the world-sheet.** As we will soon see, spacetime supersymmetry arises only after we combine states from the Ramond and Neveu–Schwarz sectors."

**Quote 2, page 320 of the same text**: " We have seen that the **Ramond sector has world-sheet supersymmetry: there are equal numbers of fermionic and bosonic states at each mass level**"

**Quote 3, page 321** of the same text: "**In order to have spacetime supersymmetry we need $f_{NS_+(x)} = f_{R_−(x)}$, or explicitly"**

**14.7 (only one page)** of the same text might help you convince yourself that you've internalized the **difference between a worldsheet fermion and a spacetime fermion.**